# Non-const pointer to this in const member function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, constants, this

I'm trying to implement a last() function for a linked list, which, when called from any node in the list, will return the final node in the list:

```
template <typename T>
LinkedList::LinkedListElement<T>* LinkedList::LinkedListElement<T>::last () const {
    LinkedList::LinkedListElement<T>* p = this;

    while(p->next) {
        p = p->next;
    }

    return p;
}
```

Since only returning the last node shouldn't change the list at all, I thought it made sense to make it a const function, although once the end user has that node, he can certainly modify the list by calling other functions, such as insert.

The compiler complains on line 3, that I'm trying to convert a const pointer to a non-const one. Apparently, making my function const caused `this` to become a constant pointer. So I've tried making p a pointer to const data, but then the line `return p;` gives the same error, that I'm trying to convert from const to non-const. Doing a const_cast when I assign p does the trick, but since casting should be avoided, I was wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Have a const and non const overload.

Comment: What you're trying to do is inherently dangerous; it allows a user to obtain a non-const pointer (or more precisely a non-to-const pointer) to a member of a const list. Any use that *requires* such a pointer is almost certain to lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: not related to your question, but as design, I wouldn’t make a node aware of the container (list) that he is in, i.e. I wouln’t put a `last` method on the node. The list alone should have a `last` method.

Comment: @bolov, we can consider every node in a singly linked list a singly linked list in its own right. This is very useful when the list is immutable.

Comment: @bolov, Don Reba: Designing every node as a list in and of itself is the design I'm using. There's no separate List object. But I do appreciate the advice, and I'm sure both designs have their merits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just consider this:

Someone calls `last()` on a `const` node that is already the last node. It returns itself, as a pointer to non-`const` node, which then can be used to modify it. This violates const correctness.

Either make the method non-`const` and return the pointer to non-`const`:

```
LinkedList::LinkedListElement<T>*
    LinkedList::LinkedListElement<T>::last ();
```

or make the method `const` and return a pointer to `const`:

```
const LinkedList::LinkedListElement<T>*
    LinkedList::LinkedListElement<T>::last () const;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for misunderstanding you.
Since the last() function may return this pointer and you want to modify it,it's better to define this function as non-const;

Comment: Your first method returns NULL or worse, and your second doesn't satisfy the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

And what about make "const *END* element" maybe like stl? Element is *END* if `(next==NULL)` and we will not use *END* for store value.

```
[LIST]->(END)                                    // empty list
[LIST]->(value1)->(value2)->(value3)->...->(END) // list with values
```

After this change, the END will be `const` all the time.

<sub>And the iteration `while (next!=NULL)` will be less buggy.</sub>

Comment: And how does that address the question?

Comment: @Beta You don't need `last()` function.

Comment: And how does one obtain a non-const pointer to either `END` or the last node containing data, which is what the OP asked for?